# Make width only as big as it needs to be

Tags: html, css

It seems CSS defaults to 100% but instead I want it to be only as wide as it needs to be including padding:

http://jsfiddle.net/Bqebp/

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: pink;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    /* width and height can be anything, as long as they're equal */
}
```

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your http://jsfiddle.net/Bqebp/1/

Just add `display:inline-block;` in your css

Comment: this one BUT a too long content can spare width and height. If your text change you need a line-height change dinamically with JS

Answer (score 2):

add `float:left` or `display:inline-block;` in css